# Возможно ли переходить к предыдущим постам или следующим, внутри самого поста

Tags: wordpress

Возможно ли переходить к предыдущим постам или следующим, внутри самого поста и если возможно то как, скиньте код желательно с проверкой если есть пост или нет

Comment: "Внутри самого поста" -  это как?

Comment: ну то есть я нахожусь на странице single-post грубо и мне нужно сделать 2 кнопки на предыдущий пост и следующий

Comment: А причем тут "внутри поста"? Это делается под его выводом.

Comment: извините наверное не так выразился, я хотел сказать что я нахожусь не на странице где я циклом вывожу все посты как бы их превью, а именно на странице одного поста и мне нужно переходить на след и пред

Comment: В ответе нужные функции.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для вывода навигационных ссылок можно использовать функции `next_posts_link`, `previous_post_link`,  или общую `the_post_navigation`.

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_post_navigation